# Rewrite the derivative of Fermi-Dirac distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

I find the derivative to the Fermi-Dirac equation as

[image]

via my textbook and this can be rewritten to

[image: ![enter image description here]

using the identities $2cosh(x)=e^{x}+e^{-x}$ and $4cosh^{2}(x)=e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2$ but I just can't make it happen. Can anyone show the steps it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Images of math and text are very strongly discouraged on the site.  Please use a combination of text and [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines:
$$\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}=\frac{(e^{\frac{x}{2}})^2}{(1+e^x)^2}=
\frac{1}{(e^{-\frac{x}{2}})^2(1+e^x)^2}=
\frac{1}{(e^{-\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}})^2}
$$